# Merging unique values and calculting percentage from a different column in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new table in R that summarizes unique values in one column and then calculates the the percentage of variables in another column.

I have a columns with county names, types of visits, service level descriptions and number of visits for for each of those service level descriptions. I'm trying to calculate the the percentage of admits to visits but I'm unsure of how to go about it.

```
head(type_sum, 10)
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Groups:   county_name, type, er_service_level_desc [10]
   county_name type     er_service_level_desc visit_count     n
   <chr>       <chr>    <chr>                       <int> <int>
 1 ALAMEDA     ED_Admit BASIC                       73500    13
 2 ALAMEDA     ED_Visit BASIC                      566702    13
 3 AMADOR      ED_Admit BASIC                        1926     1
 4 AMADOR      ED_Visit BASIC                       20806     1
 5 BUTTE       ED_Admit BASIC                       27906     3
 6 BUTTE       ED_Admit STANDBY                       246     1
 7 BUTTE       ED_Visit BASIC                       90856     3
 8 BUTTE       ED_Visit STANDBY                     10406     1
 9 CALAVERAS   ED_Admit BASIC                         768     1
10 CALAVERAS   ED_Visit BASIC                       10856     1
```

I've tried a number of different approaches to the problem but right now I'm stuck at...

```
# Percentage of admits to visits

ca_admit_perc <- type_sum %>%
  filter_by(county_name) %>% ???
```

It's completely possible that I'm approaching the problem all wrong. If so, please let me know.

edit::
I'm probably not asking the question correctly. My expected outcome I'm trying to achieve is:

```
# Outcome columns I'm looking for:
county_name     Admit percentage(ED_Admit/ED_Visit * 100)
```

Just a little disclaimer, I've been teaching myself R for a little less than a month and have started to dig down in to personal projects. I've seen similar problems in tutorials and books but it's usually very basic and only goes over calculating one or two columns. This is my first time using stackoverflow so forgive me if this is the wrong type of question to ask here. Constructive criticism is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide your expected output for the sample data you give? I am unclear what you're trying to calculate here. For example, you want to calculate *"the percentage of admits to visits"* relative to *what*? Does `n` play any role in this? Do you just want to group by `county_name` or also by `type`? Is `er_service_level_desc` important?

Comment: I just added some clarification to the original post as to the outcome I'm looking for and apologize for not being more clear. er_service_level_desc doesn't matter at the moment. "n" doesn't matter at all is just a column I forgot to remove from the original table. I appreciate the help.

Comment: So what happens if you have multiple `ED_Admit`s (with different `er_service_level_desc` types)? Will they be summed? Averaged?

Comment: Good question. As I'm working through the data set,  I was going add the 'er_service_level_desc' once I figure out how to get the total averages. Which, I believe the answer you posted will work well. I'm going to play around with it more and add that piece next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(county_name, type) %>%
    summarise(visit_count = sum(visit_count)) %>%
    spread(type, visit_count) %>%
    mutate(admit_percentage = ED_Admit / ED_Visit * 100) %>%
    ungroup()
## A tibble: 4 x 4
#  county_name ED_Admit ED_Visit admit_percentage
#  <fct>          <int>    <int>            <dbl>
#1 ALAMEDA        73500   566702            13.0
#2 AMADOR          1926    20806             9.26
#3 BUTTE          28152   101262            27.8
#4 CALAVERAS        768    10856             7.07
```

Explanation: We first group by `county_name` and `type` and summarise `visit_count`
by summing multiple entries. We then reshape the data from long to wide to create an `ED_Admit` and `ED_Visit` column, before calculating `admit_percentage` as per your request.

If instead of summing you want to average multiple `visit_count`s for the same `county_name` and `type` you can replace `sum` with `mean`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
"   county_name type     er_service_level_desc visit_count     n
 1 ALAMEDA     ED_Admit BASIC                       73500    13
 2 ALAMEDA     ED_Visit BASIC                      566702    13
 3 AMADOR      ED_Admit BASIC                        1926     1
 4 AMADOR      ED_Visit BASIC                       20806     1
 5 BUTTE       ED_Admit BASIC                       27906     3
 6 BUTTE       ED_Admit STANDBY                       246     1
 7 BUTTE       ED_Visit BASIC                       90856     3
 8 BUTTE       ED_Visit STANDBY                     10406     1
 9 CALAVERAS   ED_Admit BASIC                         768     1
10 CALAVERAS   ED_Visit BASIC                       10856     1", header = T)
```

Comment: For clarification, I already spotted an area where I messed up in describing my problem. I corrected the calculating of percentages to be `mutate(admit_percentage = ED_Admit / (ED_Admit + ED_Visit) * 100)` to get the percentage of all visits. The data set is from the California hospitals. I wanted the get the percentage of ED_Admits from all ED encounters so I had to add visits and admits before I divide to get the percentage. Again, the help is greatly appreciated.